# PHP при AJAX-запросе воспринимается как текст

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, ajax, php, php.ini

При нажатии на кнопку происходит ajax-запрос на файл обработчик. Этот файл должен брать из бд данные и формировать html. На локалке все работает. На хостинге все содержимое php-файла-обработчика воспринимается как текст. Неважно, что написано в php, все равно выдается как текст. Например, в php написано `<?php echo "test"; ?>`. В результате я не получу слово `"test"` а получу `<--?php echo "test"; ?-->`.

Что делать? В чем проблема?

**Upd**

Заметил, что если обращаться к php-файлам напрямую (например, http://site.ru/index.php) то они скачиваются, а не обрабатываются, как надо. Может, в этом проблема? Как ее решить?

**Upd 2**

Проблема решена. Хостер настроил сервер таким образом, чтобы при обращении к php-файлам напрямую происходило скачивание этих файлов. Дурацкий хостинг...

Comment: Это, конечно, маловероятно, но может на хостинге php нету?

Comment: На хостинге есть php. Все страницы нормально генерируются. PHP воспринимается как текст только при ajax-запросе

Answer (score 1):

Одно из двух - либо почему-то отключена обработка PHP-файлов собственно интерпретатором, либо, что вероятнее, что-то мешается, ибо между `<?` не должно быть символов, а у тебя есть, поэтому сервер не воспринимает этот текст как php-код.
Почему - это уже другой вопрос, нужно смотреть, что там тебе файлы переписывает.

Comment: Между <? нет символов. Это браузер выводит php как html-комментарий. В php-файле написано <?php echo "test"; ?> И эта строка воспринимается как текст и вставляется браузером в страницу как html-комментарий

Comment: PHP обрабатывается на сервере, если до клиента (браузера) доходит код, то проблема точно на сервере, как обрабатывает полученное браузер - дело последнее.

Comment: Ну в общем-то. Вопрос: почему сервер отдает php как текст?